# Moving messages from DLQ to main subscription is omitting the body of message

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus

We are in process of handling messages in DLQ for one of the subscription in our Servicebus and as we were not able to move them in main subscription using Logic App/ Azure Function, we tried to move messages from DLQ to main subscription using Service Bus Explorer but after transfer of messages we observed that, size of message is only 4 Bytes and in DLQ it was in MBs.

We also observed that if we are adding new message to DLQ and moving that message to main subscription then it works, but for existing messages that are 5-6 months old are having issue while moving those or processing those using Logic App/ Function App

Any clue on why this is not working as it should be?